# Gazebo Fortress GUI on a different machine

Tags: ignition-fortress

I am trying to setup a simulation environment like `[this][1]` with the following variation: I would like to have Gazebo running on one machine (MACHINE A) and access the data (topics) from another (MACHINE B), with both machines being on the same LAN. I can probably setup the ros-bridge on MACHINE A and then rely on the ROS infrastructure to get the topics on MACHINE B. **But the main issue now is to have the Gazebo GUI on MACHINE B**: searching on the web I have found a couple of [broken links](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26549/how-do-i-run-ignition-gazebo-distributed-server-on-one-machine-gui-on-another/), some [others](https://community.gazebosim.org/t/how-can-i-run-an-ign-gazebo-server-client-pair-with-websocket/1650) mention IGN_PARTITION but I did not succeed.

Thanks for the help